# Touchpad randomly clicks when lid closed after updating Synaptics touchpad

Tags: drivers, synaptics-touchpad

After updating my Synaptics touchpad driver to the latest version from the Synaptics website (Older versions had a bug and I couldn't enable moving the mouse while typing), my touchpad is randomly clicking around the screen when the lid is closed. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Oh... I just realized what's happening. The lid is pressing down on the touchpad, and now that Palm Check is disabled, it's successfully clicking around the screen.

The problem wasn't the new driver version but rather me being able to successfully disable Palm Check!