# Touchpad randomly move and click

Tags: windows, laptop, touchpad

My touchpad randomly move and click around the screen, while lid is open: left-clic, right click, fast move (consequently drag-and-drop, open/close windows, etc.). It happens also after reboot. It happens also while USB mouse is connected.

Laptop is Dell Inspiron 5570, operating system is Windows 7. Issue happened also on another laptop (AsusPro P230UJ) on which is installed windows 10.

I have re-installed touchpad drivers, it did not helped.

No virus or malware found, scanned with many tools.

Already seen [Touchpad randomly clicks when lid closed after updating Synaptics touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/1272835/touchpad-randomly-clicks-when-lid-closed-after-updating-synaptics-touchpad) and other Q/A, but it's not my case.

What could be the root cause? Thank you.

Comment: What are your computer and touchpad models?

Comment: _"Tested also with another laptop"_ - how did you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved. On both the laptop was installed a software for serial log acquisition via usb. It seems a sort of interference on serial bus happens when the software is running.

Removing this software solved the issue.

Thank you